# How to identify a change in a websites’ structure programmatically

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, health-monitoring

Within the implementation of a Python Scrapy crawler I would like to add a robust mechanism for monitoring/detecting potential layout changes within a website.

These changes do not *necessarily* affect existing spider selectors - for example, a site adds a new HTML element to represent the number of visitors an item has received - an element I might now be interested in parsing. 
Having said that, detecting selector issues (Xpath/CSS) would be also beneficial in case where they are removed/relocated.

Please note this is not about selector content change or a website refresh (`if-modified-since` or `last-modified`), but rather a modification in the structure / nodes / layout of a site.

Therefore, how would one implement logic to monitor such circumstances?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a topic for research as you can see on [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7785739) but there are of course some implemented tools that you can check out:

- https://github.com/matiskay/html-similarity
- https://github.com/matiskay/html-cluster
- https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/page-compare

Basically the base for comparing (on the previous approaches) is to use the [Tree Edit Distance](http://tree-edit-distance.dbresearch.uni-salzburg.at/) of the html layout.

Comment: Perfect will play around with Matiskay’s repos, they seem to potentially cover the Boolean question of “has it changed?” albeit not which node has changed but for now that would do - thanks!!

Comment: I think you'll have to define a threshold maybe for the sites you are comparing, as like "identical" structure means it didn't change, but sites can also add meta tags or even just some `p` tags (not so relevant stuff) which could affect layout structure in a minimal way. Hope I helped you find a way to solve your problem.

Comment: Got it. Will try it out 